# IAM role with rds:CreateDBClusterSnapshot cannot create cluster snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I want to create a web interface on an EC2 instance to "shutdown" and "start" an RDS Aurora cluster because it is only used for 2 days a month.

To do this I have:

- created a role with

  "Action": [
              "rds:CreateDBClusterSnapshot",
              "rds:CreateDBCluster",
              "rds:DeleteDBCluster"
          ],
          "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:rds:us-west-2:123456789:cluster:momtransgrinder-cluster"
          ]
- associated the role with the instance

When I run the following command:

```
  aws rds create-db-cluster-snapshot --db-cluster-snapshot-identifier testsnap2 --db-cluster-identifier momtransgrinder-cluster
```

I get an error

```
  An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateDBClusterSnapshot operation: User: arn:aws:sts::123456789:assumed-role/root/i-47717451 is not authorized to perform: rds:CreateDBClusterSnapshot on resource: arn:aws:rds:us-west-2:123456789:cluster-snapshot:testsnap2
```

However, when I change the role to have rds:*, it works. There must be some implicit other permission needed to create the cluster snapshot? But which one?

Answer (score 3):

The actions you defined need to be associated to the RDS cluster as well as the snapshots you create. Currently your `Resource` field is missing snapshot term, thats why you see the error:

```
not authorized .. on resource: arn:aws:rds:us-west-2:123456789:cluster-snapshot:testsnap
```

So if you add cluster snapshots as resource targets like below, you should get rid of this particular error

```
"Resource": [ "arn:aws:rds:us-west-2:123456789:cluster:momtransgrinder-cluster", 
              "arn:aws:rds:us-west-2:123456789:cluster-snapshot:testsnap2" ]
```

However I'd recommend giving a wildcard entry on the snapshot assuming you will be creating multiple snapshots, identifiers of which may well be only known at runtime. Also, I found success adding some of the other related actions on the snapshot as well. I am not sure if `rds:CreateDBClusterSnapshot` is sufficient. All in all, this is how I would do given your case:

```
  {
      "Action": [
        "rds:CopyDBClusterSnapshot",
        "rds:CopyDBSnapshot",
        "rds:CreateDBClusterSnapshot",
        "rds:CreateDBSnapshot",
        "rds:DeleteDBClusterSnapshot",
        "rds:DeleteDBSnapshot",
        "rds:DescribeDBClusterSnapshotAttributes",
        "rds:DescribeDBClusterSnapshots",
        "rds:DescribeDBSnapshots",
        "rds:DescribeDBSnapshotAttributes",
        "rds:ModifyDBClusterSnapshotAttribute",
        "rds:ModifyDBSnapshot",
        "rds:ModifyDBSnapshotAttribute"
      ],
      "Resource": [
         "arn:aws:rds:us-west-2:123456789:cluster:momtransgrinder-cluster",
         "arn:aws:rds:us-west-2:123456789:cluster-snapshot:*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": "CreateSnapshot"
  }
```

Comment: I don't have the cluster available anymore to test this, but I'm sure it will help someone. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

Since the snapshot you are trying to create is copied from another existing snapshot, you'll need to add to your role, a statement to allow this action such as:

```
{      
     "Action": [
         "rds:CopyDBClusterSnapshot",
         "rds:CopyDBSnapshot"
     ],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": "arn:aws:rds:us-west-2:123456789:cluster-snapshot:testsnap2"
}
```

Hope it helps !